# How to connect mobile to laptop to browse internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I want to access my laptop through mobile (Motorola Motorokr E6) to browse the internet.
Is it possible?

Can files/folders of laptop can be access through mobile?

Any software or anything which is required, please share it. Both of them have bluetooth.

Also, to share with you, I have Netgear box which connects my laptop and desktop for file sharing and internet sharing. Can I include my mobile also?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually possible to "tether" a phone to a PC and use it to get internet connectivity.

However, it is heavily dependant on your service provider. So the best thing for you to do is contact your service provider and ask them if "tethering" is available and what their fees would be. They will then be able to provide you with instructions for your phone, on their network.

Comment: I think the OP wants to go the other direction.

Comment: @Dennis I think you're right now that I read it again. Hopfully someone else can provide a more appropriate answer.